# iOS Universal Link not working on HTTP

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I'm trying to open an App from a Web Page link, it works like a charm on an HTTPS domain, but when I try on a HTTP (unsecure) domain the universal link isn't working.

Anyone know if I'm missing a configuration?.

Thank you!.

Comment: iOS is blocking http by default.  You have add keys to the plist check out this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: This is not the case, Allow Arbitrary Loads worked for App-Web Services communication, but in Universal Links I don't think is used

Comment: You are right.  Didn't realize that you are talking about universal link

Comment: is there any solution ? but apple documentation say, it will works :https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: did u find the sol?

Answer (score 5):

If I am understanding correctly, you have an app for which you are enabling Universal Links. When the associated-domain that you are using for Universal Linking is secured by SSL, everything is working properly. When you attempt to use a link domain that is not secured by SSL, however, it is not working.

Assuming I have understood correctly, the issue you are encountering is most likely Apple's requirement that the AASA file be served securely on your link domain. As per Apple's documentation (here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html):

> After you create the apple-app-site-association file, upload it to the root of your HTTPS web server or to the .well-known subdirectory. The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects—at https:///apple-app-site-association or https:///.well-known/apple-app-site-association. Next, you need to handle universal links in your app.

Comment: Thanks!, so HTTPS is needed in this case