# universal link with invalid certificate of website(http not https)

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-universal-links

I have configure and implemented Universal link with react native. It is working fine with another configure url but not working with a **website which website's site certificate is invalid**.

is there any workaround to fixed it?

Example:
my website is at "http://www.mywebsite.com?code=1"

Will universal link work at http domain?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your issue, but it reminds me of something I recently encountered when setting up deep links with React Navigation. When I tapped `xx.com` in the Notes app, iOS automatically prefixed it with `http://`, not `https`. This still opened the app without additional configuration, but it messed up handling/parsing the link until we realized it.

Comment: check question please

Comment: Have a look at ATS - App Transport Security: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity Apple does not allow network connections without proper TLS/SSL and valid certificates. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601938/ios-universal-link-not-working-on-http

Comment: @Adriano let me check

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: mentioned: Unique. Unlike custom URL schemes, universal links can’t be claimed by other apps, because they use standard HTTP or HTTPS links to your website.

Comment: what does it mean.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid certificate may occur as

- expired
- has always been invalid because is buggy or similar issues
- certificate is valid, but the old browser has an outdated white list of certificates - without the needed one
- the page does not have ssl which is required for some on-line activities and `may be treated as invalid certificate`

Security Certificate is required for acting like payment, logging etc.
The criterion (for google) is the <input> on a page and probably app link (not sure, but convinced).

Yes, I know google isn't apple, but apple is even more focused on security and access (you can't even change memory chips).

I ran a test once - created a http page and link to it as https - my opera (Google affiliate browser) got apoplexy. And yes, the input was involved - it was logging into a page with no content. It does not matter that login and password were not required. Doesn't check what kind of input is. They say it even search google widget counts. The same rules for apps.

According to above - no, I don't think that's possible. Theoretically yes, but in real life it will not work because you cannot avoid google and apple, you have to follow their rules.
`There are plenty free Certificates` (ask google for "certificate ssl free"), you don't have to quit.

Answer (score 0):

Universal link without SSL is indeed supported in the past, I have seen it in the official documentation. You need codesign the json file. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/11948

But it seems that https is a must have now. You should follow the guide https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content